# EPiServer 6 Site Center breaks in Visual Studio Development Server

Tags: episerver

I've installed an EPiServer 6 site locally and it is running fine in IIS, but when I open it as a solution in Visual Studio 2008 and run it via the built in development server, the site center dashboard page doesn't work, I get a 404 error.

I guess there is some configuration in IIS that needs to be set up in Visual Studio? Has anyone figured this out already?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem was that I used the EPiServer Deployment Centre to create a website in IIS7, which created an web.config file customised for IIS7. So when I tried to run the website from the Visual Studio development server (which behaves like IIS6), the web.config file was not compatible.

I created a new site using the Visual Studio EPiServer Project template, which created a website which worked when run through the Visual Studio development server.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have ASP.NET MVC 1 installed?

Comment: Yes I have installed MVC 1.0. When I go to the EPiServer site dashboard I get a directory listing.

     Thursday, April 01, 2010 09:41 AM        <dir> CMS
     Thursday, April 01, 2010 09:42 AM        <dir> Shell

However, the dashboard works if I use IIS instead of the built in VS2008 development server.